# Is there a way to find my last visited questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I always search in my history browser to find the last questions that I have visited recently, so I spend a lot of time trying to search in my history browser which contains a lot of links. Some times I can't find the link if I cleared the history cache or if I'm connected from an other PC.

It's really easy to realize this feature, this will be done, just by storing the ID of the current subject, and list all those links on a page on the activity tab, or just a client side solution that list all the recent visited subjects on the current session.

Comment: Downvotes? Again!!! More downvotes and It will be my last question --", and I will always use history browser for the rest of my life!

Comment: FWIW I didn't downvote. Question votes are used to express agreement/disagreement on meta, which makes it unlike the rest of StackExchange.

Comment: I found reading [How to participate in meta and not die trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying) strangely comforting when I was new to meta, despite finding parts of it objectionable, at least I knew what was going on more.

Comment: You've already written this to me :D, thanks.

Comment: (It helped me come to terms with being downvoted for suggesting something and being told off for being whiny. I don't think you're being whiny at all, but I certainly went there.)

Comment: @Quadie Oh yeah - [so I did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147873/what-about-having-more-information-about-a-question-before-viewing-it#comment424723_147888), sorry I didn't recognise you! :)

Comment: Normal! Im 'O'uadie not 'Q'uadie. Now you can recognize me the next time :)

Comment: Oh, that explains it! Of course! I should pay more attention. My mistake, I do apologise. :D

Comment: As a mod, I'd find something like this useful in cases where I go digging through a bunch of questions to find examples of stuff. My browsing makes relying on my history a little inconvenient. But, I'd want it _hard_ to accidentally do, and I'd want it to use local storage. That kind of leads to a user script. I don't know if enough people would want it to make it an actual 'local bookmark' feature.

Comment: By the way, you have this tagged as feature-request, but it seems more like a support question where 'and if not, please add this' is implied. That might be part of the reason you see down votes. To implement a feature, you should describe how it would work, what the benefit would be, and ideally address concerns you think people are likely to have.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds nice at first, but it would have the disadvantage that the site would have to track and record all your browsing on the site, which feels a little intrusive to some people, and would result in an awful lot more data getting stored. (I *read* a lot more than I *do*, for example.)

As your browser has this functionality built in, it's only if you've cleared the history cache that this information is unavailable to you.

There's a record of [your *actions*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625952/ouadie?tab=activity&sort=all) which you can see by clicking on your profile and going to the Activity tab and clicking All. This nicely complements the browser history by showing you where you clicked and typed.

Comment: I don't think that's difficult to manage, especially if they have just to store the ID of the current subject that's all!, if not, a client side solution will be efficient.